# Is there an X twitter icon in flutter?

Tags: flutter, icons

Is there an X twitter icon in flutter? Most of the twitter icons are the old one. I need the X logo.

I tried material_symbols_icons and cupertino_icons but there's none. I also tried font_awesome_flutter `FontAwesomeIcons.xTwitter` but returns empty icon.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the X [Brand guideline](https://about.twitter.com/en/who-we-are/brand-toolkit), Download logo and use it. You can use ImageIcon widget to convert image into Icons or You can directly use svg.

Answer (score 0):

No twitter's X logos were found in the flutter icon library. I believe you can use **Flat Icon** or **Font Awesome Icons**. You can get the X icons for mentioned platforms in following links:

[FontAwesome Twitter's X logo](https://fontawesome.com/search?q=twitter&o=r)

[FlatIcons Twitter's X logo](https://www.flaticon.com/search?word=twitter)